# How is my counter3 correctly incrementing the loop?

Tags: c

So not sure how my counter3 while loop is ending.  I was trying to increment it by `+1` but that was printing too many rows of *.  Randomly added `counter3 = counter3 + input` and it ended the loop correctly.  How is this possible because then it seems like the loop would end after the first time.  An assignment was to take the user input of an integer and make an empty box of * that size using while loops. So if the user enters 5 the box should be 7x7.  I put **()** for the parts in question. Code below:

```
//Homework 3 - Question 8

//main.c

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int input, input1, counter = 0, counter2 = 0, counter3 = 0, counter4 = 0, counter5 = 0;


    printf("Enter an integer between 1 and 20: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);


    while (counter < (input + 2) ){
        printf("* ");
        counter += 1;
    }


    **while (counter3 < input)** { 

        counter2 = 0;  

        while (counter2 < input ){  
            printf("\n* ");
            counter4 = 0;  

            while (counter4 < input){  
                printf("  ");
                counter4 +=1;  
            }

            printf("*");  
            counter2 +=1;  
        }

        **counter3 = counter3 + input;**  
    }

    printf("\n");

    while (counter5 < (input + 2) ){
        printf("* ");
        counter5 += 1;
    }


    printf("\n");

    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: Why don't you `for (int counter = 0; counter < input; counter += input)`? Just of the sake of readability of this code, this all are beauty for loops.

Comment: @KamilCuk the assignment was to use `while` loops

Comment: How many times are you expecting `*.`? 'Too many' is a bit vague

Answer (score 0):

Because the loop with counter3 is not needed. You can remove the lines in question (with the enclosing `}` of the while, and program will stay the same. The `while (counter3 < input)` runs only once, it doesn't loop, it can be removed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int input, input1, counter = 0, counter2 = 0, counter3 = 0, counter4 = 0, counter5 = 0;


    printf("Enter an integer between 1 and 20: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);


    while (counter < (input + 2) ){
        printf("* ");
        counter += 1;
    }


        counter2 = 0;  

        while (counter2 < input ){  
            printf("\n* ");
            counter4 = 0;  

            while (counter4 < input){  
                printf("  ");
                counter4 +=1;  
            }

            printf("*");  
            counter2 +=1;  
        }


    printf("\n");

    while (counter5 < (input + 2) ){
        printf("* ");
        counter5 += 1;
    }


    printf("\n");

    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: got it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I was trying to increment it by +1 but that was printing too many rows of *.
>
> How is this possible because then it seems like the loop
> would end after the first time.

That's not true at all. `counter3` is initialized to 0 and you were incrementing its value by 1. Assuming that `input > 0`, then `counter3 < input` will remain true until `counter3 == input` then the loop will terminate. The reason it works the way you want it to with the code you added is because now you are incrementing the value of `counter3` so that it becomes greater than the value of `input` on the first iteration so the statement `counter3 < input` is now `false` and the loop terminates.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first rules you need to learn in programming is the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

You're trying to read a number and then print an `n + 2` by `n + 2` square of `*`s.

So you just want two loops, an outer loop that prints a row for each iteration, and an inner loop that prints a `*` for each iteration.

```
int input = 0, counter = 0, counter1 = 0;
scanf("%d", &input);

// Increase input by 2 to get the true size of the square
input += 2;

// outer loop to print rows
while (counter < input)
{
    // inner loop to print '*'s
    counter1 = 0;
    while (counter1 < input)
    {
        // print your '*' here, with any needed spaces
        counter1++;
    }
    // end of row, print your newline character here
    counter++;
}
```

That's doing it with `while` loops, which may be what the instructor has specifically asked for.  However since this is such a common pattern in C, a `for` loop allows you a more compact expression:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < input; counter++)
{
    for (counter1 = 0; counter1 < input; counter1++)
    {
```

does the exact same thing placing the initialization and the increment of the counter variable all on the same line.